# Undefined offset: 1 For Loop PHP

Tags: php

The array it is fetching has size 2 , so if we comment out `$size` it returns 2 , but the for loop prints only the value present at 0th position of table column and not the next at 2th giving the error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

**Code:**

```
$allunstitched="Select p_id from unstitchedproduct";
$resultAllUnstitched= mysqli_query($connection,$allunstitched);
$AllUnstitchedResult= mysqli_fetch_array($resultAllUnstitched);
//$size=count($AllUnstitchedResult);

for ($i=0, $count = count($AllUnstitchedResult); $i < $count; ++$i) {
  print $AllUnstitchedResult[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, i dont think you have a problem in your for-loop; since your query reads *ONE* field/column  it should have **1** iteration  *(=0 index)*, so the *=1 undefined* is correct (in my opinion).

What you should do is a loop that calls repeatedly `mysqli_fetch_array` to get all rows, like this:

```
while($AllUnstitchedResult = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAllUnstitched,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
   foreach ($AllUnstitchedResult as $field) {
      print $field;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using mysqli_fetch_array. This function returns the result twice by default: indexed both by number and by column name. Here the result set has only one column, so you get its value twice in the array: first with index 0 and then with a string index. There is no index 1.

To get the results with numerical indexes only, pass MYSQLI_NUM as a second argument to mysqli_fetch_array:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($resultAllUnstitched, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start at 0, if count = 5 you'll have 6 elements (0,1,2,3,4,5), beware of that. You need to loop (`count-1`) times:

```
 $count = count($AllUnstitchedResult);
 for ($i=0, $i < $count-1; $i++) {
    print $AllUnstitchedResult[$i];
 }
```

Comment: Right now I have 2 values in the database , so count is 2 and $i=0 ,so the loop is ok !

Comment: This way you don't process the last item in the array.